# Wireless SSID broadcast using Python

Tags: python-2.7, ssid, wifi

**Hi all I am trying to write a python code to broadcast an SSID created by using Python.**

- Is there a library Written for something like  that which i could
  install?
- Is it really possible to write such a code to cause my wifi
  card broad cast an SSID i created?

Answer (score 1):

aircrack-ng suite use airbase-ng to broadcast or hostapd (if you want to do more than just broadcast). In terms of python not really, you could use subprocess and execute airbase-ng through your script. If you want pure python, best to get Scapy and do it through there.